# Аккордеон, получение всегда первый Id. ASP.NET Core and Ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, asp.net-core

При нажатии на любое сообщения из списка, получает всегда id того элемента который стоит первый. Почему?

Вот код:

**Html**

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    if (item.Status == "New")
    {
        <div class="panel panel-default" data-id="@item.Id"  onclick="GetMessageId()" id="clickId">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <a class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="collapse"  href="#imageGallery-@item.Id" style="width: 100%">
                    <h4 style="color: white; text-align: left; width: auto; z-index: 3">
                        От: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployeeTo.Name) -
                        <strong> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)</strong>
                    </h4>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body collapse" id="imageGallery-@item.Id">
                <strong style="color: dimgrey">Заголовок:</strong><h5> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)</h5><br />
                <div style="width: 100%">
                    <strong style="color: dimgrey">Содержимое</strong> <h4>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Content)</h4>
                </div> <br /><hr />
                <p style="color: dimgrey">Дата отправки: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateFrom) </p>
                <a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showModalSendOrderAdmin()">Переслать</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

**Ajax запрос**

```
var idMessage;
    function GetMessageId() {
        var messageId = document.getElementById('clickId');
        idMessage = messageId.getAttribute('data-id');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("OrderStatus", "OrderEmployees")',
            data: {
                idMessage: idMessage
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log('success!');
            }
        });
    }
```

**Метод**

```
public ActionResult OrderStatus(string idMessage)
        {
            var messageId = _context.OrderEmployees.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == idMessage);
            if (messageId != null && messageId.Status == "New")
            {
                messageId.Status = "Open";
                _context.Update(messageId);
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что Вы пытаетесь здесь получиться `document.getElementById('clickId');` ? Проблема в том, что скорее всего вы просто ловите первый элемент, и на этом все.

Comment: @Dmitry Я нажимаю на сообщение, и по идее должен получить id сообщения которое нажал.

Comment: @Dmitry А, как поймать нужный элемент?

Comment: А можно скрин DOM дерева ваших сообщений?

Comment: Ну давайте попробуем разобраться. Вы вешаете `onclick` на `div`, и по идее, когда мы на него нажимаем, мы переходим в функцию `GetMessageId`, а там вы уже пытаетесь достать `messageId` с помощью `document.getElementById('clickId');`, у меня появляется вопрос, откуда вы берете `clickId`? Попробуйте в параметры функции дописать `event`, а после сделайте вывод данной переменной, и просмотрите что в ней находиться.

Comment: @Dmitry А, куда именно eveynt, нужно поместить? Я в ajax и js только начинаю разбираться.

Comment: Чтож, я думаю можно попробовать написать ответ, секунду...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Суть вашей проблемы была в том, что вы доставали неправильные данные.

Давайте разберемся, вы вешаете `onclick` на `div`, и по идее, когда мы на него нажимаем, мы переходим в функцию `GetMessageId`, там мы получим с помощью `event.target`, наш `div`, а с помощью метода `getAttribute` достанем нужный нам `id` и запишем его в `messageId`.

Вот и все.

```
onclick="GetMessageId(this)"
```

```js
function GetMessageId(event) {
    var messageId = event.getAttribute('data-id');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("OrderStatus", "OrderEmployees")',
        data: {
            idMessage: messageId
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('success!');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: У меня возвращает null

Comment: Вот здесь у меня нужный id находиться. `dataset: DOMStringMap
id: "7121bb34-b66a-4975-9fd4-947cbf444b45"
toggle: "collapse"
__proto__: DOMStringMap`

Comment: В обьекте `event` ? Просмотрите или `event` не пустой

Comment: Вот, что в event-е приходит.`MouseEvent {isTrusted: true, screenX: 740, screenY: 463, clientX: 700, clientY: 332, …}` а, в нём `dataset: DOMStringMap id: "7121bb34-b66a-4975-9fd4-947cbf444b45" toggle: "collapse" __proto__: DOMStringMap`

Comment: Тогда давайте пропишем вот так `event.target.dataset.id`

Comment: вот так сделал вроде работает. `var messageId = event.getAttribute('data-id');`

Comment: Чудно! Если я вам помог, буду благодарен за отметку "Решено"

Comment: и в метод передал `onclick="GetMessageId(this)`

Comment: Я рад, что я Вас навел на верное решение!)

Comment: Спасибо! Добавь в ответ ещё про this